# Multiple data from API not appearing in correct order-Tumblr and Last.fm

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, api, tumblr

I have a list of my recent Tumblr audio posts coming in through the Tumblr API and with each post, an artist summary from the Last.fm API is attached. I have the data coming in correctly, but the audio posts are not showing up in chronological order. Every time I refresh the page, they appear in random order. I would like to have the most recent audio post appear at the top. Here is my code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var user = "nycxnc";
        var key =  "###";
        var type = "audio";
        var limit = "5";
        var url = "https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/" + user +
            ".tumblr.com/posts/" + type + "?callback=?&filter=" + type +
            "&limit=" + limit + "" + key + "";
        $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            $.each(data.response.posts, function(i, item) {
                var artist = item.artist;
                var track = item.track_name;
                var url2 =
                    "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getInfo&track=" +
                    track + "&artist=" + artist +
                    "&api_key=###&autocorrect=1&format=json&callback=?";
                $.getJSON(url2, function(data) {
                    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                        artist_summary = item.bio.summary;
                        artist_image = item.image[4]["#text"];
                        $(".au-wrapper").append(
                            '<div class="audio-wrapper"><img src=' + artist_image +
                            '><div class="audio-meta"><span class="audio-title">' +
                            track + '</span><div class="audio-artist">' + artist +
                            '</div></div><div class="url">' + artist_summary +
                            '</div></div>');
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

How can I combine the data from two API in the correct order, if the second JSON url (Last.fm) is dependent on data from the Tumblr API? I'm new to Javascript and I'm creating this script as a learning experiment, so any help would be very appreciated. (: Thank you.

Comment: In the API [documentation](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2) I not found how set order. You can save data in a temporary array, sort it and then print ordered result.

Comment: I will try that and see if I have any luck, thank you. (:

Comment: I tried re-writing the code so that the artist summary is appended separately--the posts are now appearing in the correct order, but the summaries are showing up multiple times in each post. Here is my updated code: [http://codepen.io/nycnc/pen/PwpJWz](http://codepen.io/nycnc/pen/PwpJWz)